# Flutter error in test widget sdk related error

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

[this test is coming in my project. it is not passing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K40Bt.png)
Can anyone explain why it is coming and why it is not passing. It is happening from the time i updated my flutter sdk. can any one explain what and why?

It is not anyway affecting my project but I want to know why it is happening.